# Unable to send email with VaporSMTPKit on a ubuntu server

Tags: swift, vapor

I'm looking for sending email with VaporSMTPKit (https://github.com/Joannis/VaporSMTPKit) on a Ubuntu Server. When I'm trying to send the email with a get request, I have an "The request timed out."

Here my code :

```
    func sendTestEmailHandler(_ req : Request) -> EventLoopFuture<String> {
        
        let email = Mail(
            from: "myemail@exemple.fr",
            to: [
                MailUser(name: "Myself", email: "myemail@exemple.fr")
            ],
            subject: "Your new mail server!",
            contentType: .plain,
            text: "You've set up mail!"
        )
        
        return req.application.sendMail(email, withCredentials: .default).map {
            return "Check your mail!"
        }
    }
```

Here's how I'm using the function :

```
routes.get("sendEmail", use : sendTestEmailHandler)
```

Here's how I'm setting the extension

```
import Foundation
import VaporSMTPKit

extension SMTPCredentials {
    static var `default`: SMTPCredentials {
        return SMTPCredentials(
            hostname: "smtp.ionos.fr",
            port: 25,
            ssl: .tls(configuration: .default),
            email: "myemail@exemple.fr",
            // a changer sur le serveur
            password: "XXXX"
        )
    }
}
```

I'm using SIDT for sending a get request like

```
http://XXXX/sendEmail
```

I'm using an email from another website (not from the server). The 25 ports are open on the website and on the server.

If you know how to deal with this problem, let me know. Thanks you very much. When I'm trying to change to another port or to POP3, I have a warning alert so I don't think it's the problem.

Comment: I have not used this package, but the example in the documentation uses `startTLS`  where you have just used `tls`  in `ssl: .tls(configuration: .default)`.

Comment: Most ISPs and Clouds block port 25. Mail hosts support secondary ports for SMTP. Use a different port number. Which one, consult their documentation. For TLS (STARTTLS), use port 587. https://www.ionos.com/help/email/general-topics/settings-for-your-email-programs-imap-pop3/

Comment: @JohnHanley, OP originally posted a comment saying my suggestion solved his problem then deleted it. Question is probably a candidate for closure if it was just a mis-copy of the example.

Comment: @Nick - the OP should not be using port 25 today. That port is universally blocked unless you are a major vendor that receives permission (unblocking). I provided a link to ionos' documentation. They do not support port 25 either. Your comment regarding STARTTLS is a transport encryption option. It has nothing to do with `The request timed out.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you, Nick, for your assistance.

I previously attempted to use ssl: .tls(configuration: .default), but the issue was resolved when I modified it to ssl: .startTLS(configuration: .default).

I appreciate everyone's help
Emmanuel

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, then the details in your original post are incomplete or wrong. Changing the encryption is not related to `The request timed out`. The request must connect before you can establish the method of transport encryption.